# Next.js 13 changes towards next-seo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, next.js13

so I've been using next-seo for a while now with Next.js 12, and everything been good.
Since my values are dynamic, I created a BaseLayout component for pages and rendered the NextSeo component in it, and got props needed to completed the default, for example:

```
const BaseLayout: React.FC<{children: React.ReactNode, pageTitle?: string, description?: string, pageLink?: string}> = ({pageTitle, pageLink, description = 'default description'}) => {
    let title: string = pageTitle ? `Site Name - ${pageTitle}` : 'Site Name';
    let canonical: string = pageLink ? `https://example.com${pageLink}` : 'https://example.com';

    return (
        <>
            <NextSeo
                title={title}
                description={description}
                canonical={canonical}
            />

            {children}
        </>
    )

export default BaseLayout;
```

This used to work well with Next 12, for example in my HomePage, I would import the base layout like

```
<BaseLayout title='Home' pageLink='/' description="my homepage"><div>Sample Home</div></BaseLayout>
```

This would generate the respective meta tags, for example:

```
<meta name="description" content="my homepage" />
```

But in Next 13, this doesn't work. It shows up in devtools, but not accessible to web crawlers. I had to manually crawl the site with python and confirm that the meta tags are not injected.

Any clue as to why please? Couldn't find any resources in Next docs or next-seo docs

I tried rolling back to Next 12, but need some features of Next 13, also, just wanted to fix this.

When I render the NextSeo component in _app.tsx, it works well tho, but its too static, and I couldn't wrap around getting the dynamism as with the component approach. Also, I wanna use SSG, so don't wanna use stuff like getInitialProps or SSR in general.

PS: Using `pages` directory, cause Next says not to use `app` dir for production, lol.

Comment: I'm using Next12 too, but not `next-seo` which seems very good, but haven't used it yet because it looks heavy (464Kb). Anyway I wonder how they manage to make it work, because in Next12, Whatsapp link preview was not getting my SEO tags when I put them in page components directly. I had to define SEO tags in `getServerSideProps` and return them along with `{ props }`. This way, `_app.tsx` will receive them, and there I used my own Seo component to parse them and put them in `<Head>`. The SEO tags from `_app.tsx` are immediately available in HTML with no need of javascript running.

Comment: @KeitelDOG, you should really checkout next-seo, in Next13, the next team adopted it.
 Also, before deploying your code to check open graph preview and meta tags, maybe you could crawl the site yourself first to see if they are actually sent in the response. Maybe Python's BeautifulSoup4 or some other scrapping package.

Comment: Yes, I'm considering using it, but only if it supports tree-shaking not to inject whole package size in my chunks. I'm using a mixture of React Native + React Native Web with NextJS. For sake of main chunk size, I already removed the React Navigation from the Web platform and use Next/Router all the way. But RN+RNW is already huge in the main chunk, so that I can't afford to put heavy packages that support tree-shaking. I'll check it to see how it increase size.